# NiFi math expression results in empty string

Tags: apache-nifi

I am implementing NiFi expression language for some string manipulation, in the UpdateAttribute processor. I am trying to do `${${file_date:indexOf(‘/’)}:minus(2)}`, where file_date is a string from prev processor. This is resulting in an empty string. However doing just `${file_date:indexOf(‘/’)` results in a number.

I am not sure if I am implementing this wrong. Any help is appreciated.

file_date -> year=2020/month=12/day=12
`${${file_date:indexOf(‘/’)}:minus(2)}` -> empty string
`${file_date:indexOf(‘/’)` -> 9

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you check the asnwer?

Answer (score 0):

`${file_date:indexOf('/'):minus(2)}`

For string: `year=2020/month=12/day=12` -> return 7

[Expression Language Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)

> We can then chain together multiple function calls, where the return value of the first function becomes the subject of the second function and its return value becomes the subject of the third function and so on. Continuing with our example, we can chain together multiple functions by using the expression ${filename:toUpper():equals('HELLO.TXT')}. There is no limit to the number of functions that can be chained together.